# Visibility="Collapsed" has no effect with GroupBoxes in grids

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a view with grids and different group boxes. Setting the visibility of all group boxes in the first row to `Collapsed` should let them disappear (which works) and make "space" for the group boxes below. They should move upwards (which doesn't work):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid Height="Auto" Name="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="GroupBox 1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (1)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Header="GroupBox 2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (2)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="GroupBox 3">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (3)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="GroupBox 4">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (4)"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="GroupBox 5">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (5)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Header="GroupBox 6">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (6)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Header="GroupBox 7">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (7)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="GroupBox 8">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (8)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="GroupBox 9">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (9)"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Header="GroupBox 2">
                <Label Content="It (doesn't) work (10)"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So there is a lot of space at the top of my view now. Where's my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify your row definitions with `Height="1*"`. This splits up the height evenly across the rows. Collapsing the content of the rows does not affect their height.

If you want your rows to resize according to the content, you should use `Height="auto"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your rows and columns have fixed heights and widths. None of them is set to `Auto`.